# How to resize a materialize css datepicker to fit inside a card?

Tags: jquery, html, css, datepicker, materialize

I am writing a login page in html using materialize css framework. So i created a card and put Login/register as tabs within the card. One of the forms includes a datepicker from materialize, but the datepicker is too big to fit in the card, so it messes up the design. Can i resize a datepicker in any way? (let me know if the source code is needed)

Answer (score 1):

You can add the [scale](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale) function to the date picker modal `.datepicker-modal`.

```css
.datepicker-modal {
  transform: scale(0.7);
}
```

this scales the date picker modal to **70%** its original scale.

Comment: I tried this but it didnt seem to help. any idea what i should try?

Comment: Try adding `transform: scale(0.7) !important;` the transform is probably being overwritten.